# #import <DTBiOSSDK/DTBiOSSDK.h> file not found inside a library

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I really need help on this thing.

I'm trying to use the following library for react native

https://github.com/KrazyLabs/react-native-amazon-tam

I followed all the steps, but without success for iOS. I keep landing in the following error.

[image: my error]

What I'm not 100% sure I'm doing correctly is this part

> NOTE It's important that you save the Amazon iOS SDK to [your project's name]/ios/Frameworks/. That is where this package looks for Amazon's DTBiOSSDK.framework.

[image: maybe wrong]

I added the framework, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank y'all